# Sqlite3 will not execute in Cygwin

Tags: sqlite, cygwin

I just downloaded the Sqlite3 command line shell for windows (http://www.sqlite.org/download.html). However when I try to run the executable in Cygwin it does not load and just hangs.

The Sqlite3 shell itself works as if I browse to it in Windows explorer it runs or if I open it in cmd it runs. How do I get it to work with Cygwin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin currently doesn't work well with interactive native programs. It has to do with the way the Cygwin terminal code works, in order to provide expected POSIX semantics to Cygwin programs.

Therefore, your best bet is to use Cygwin's own SQLite package.

If you absolutely must use the native `sqlite3.exe`, you'll have use `cmd.exe` to run sqlite3.

Comment: I didn't even think to check if Cygwin had its own SQLite package. I'll just use that one, cheers.